# Get Javascript calculator to do an equation like (5-3+2) with only 2 number inputs

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm making this Javascript Calculator and I can't figure out how to get the calculator to do a problem like 5-(3+1), 5-3+1.
It only prints the 5-3 part of the equation not the +1
Here is my code:

```
<html>
<script>
function calc()
{
var D = "";
var A = document.getElementById("num1").value;
var B = document.getElementById("op").value;
var C = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
if(B == "+")
{
    D = parseInt(A)+parseInt(C);
}
else if(B == "-")
{
    D = parseInt(A)-parseInt(C);
}
else if(B == "*")
{
    D = parseInt(A)*parseInt(C);
}
else if(B == "/")
{
    D = parseInt(A)/parseInt(C);
}
else
{
    alert("Error")
}
document.getElementById("result").value = parseInt(D);
}
function conteq()
{
var D = document.getElementById("result").value;
var E = "";
document.getElementById("num1").value = D;
document.getElementById("op").value = E;
document.getElementById("num2").value = E;
    document.getElementById("result").value = E;
}
function resetcalc()
{
    var E = "";
    document.getElementById("num1").value = E;
    document.getElementById("op").value = E;
    document.getElementById("num2").value = E;
    document.getElementById("result").value = E;
}
</script>

<body>
<table align="center">
<td>This is a basic Javascript Calculator.<br /></td></table>
<table align="center"><td>(Number 1)<input type="text" id="num1" align="middle" name="num1" />
</td>
<table align="center"><td>(Operator)<input type="text" align="middle" id="op" name="op" /></td>    </table>
<table align="center"> <td>(Number 2)<input type="text" align="middle" id="num2" name="num2" /></td>  </table>
<table align="center"> <td><input type="button" align="middle" value="=" onClick="calc()" /></td>    </table>
<table align="center"><td>(Result)<input type="text" id="result" name="result" readonly />
</td></table>

<table align="center"><td><input type="button" value="Set Answer to Number 1" onClick="conteq()"    /></td></table>
<table align="center"><td><input type="button" value="Reset" onClick="resetcalc()" /></td></table>
</table>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry If I didnt understand the question, but if you are reading two numbers and one operator, in separate fields, how would you achieve a 5-3+1 expression?  Or you put more number and operator fields, or you parse the entire expression in one field.

Comment: parseInt won't cope with the brackets, it'll stop parsing as soon as it finds something that's not a number. You'll need to parse the syntax properly. Although (as I suspect this is for a school assignment) you could cheat and use eval() directly.

Comment: Made http://jsfiddle.net/ET3yG/ to try and experiment with OP's code

Comment: `eval()` is a massive security risk - the best way forward is to use a prebuilt library (e.g. http://slikcalc.selfcontained.us).

Comment: Of course eval() is a security risk, but for a school project, I'd just hand this in "<input id="txSum" value="2+2" onblur="result.innerText = eval(value);"/><div id="result"></div>". Along with an explanation of why it's bad. You might get an 'A for being a smart-arse :)

Comment: Seriously though, you probably need to use regEx to parse out the brackets otherwise. If it were me, I'd probably use regEx to safely santise the input restricting it to brackets, numbers and operators and then just use eval(). +1 for the pre-built lib tho.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert ( to an integer, and you can't (because it isn't):

```
function calc()
{
    var D = "";
    var A = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var B = document.getElementById("op").value;
    var C = document.getElementById("num2").value;

    D = eval(A + B + C);


    document.getElementById("result").value = D;
}
```

Comment: You want to regEx A,B and C to strip out anything that's not a numerical forumla to stop people injecting `<script/>` tags into the fields etc.

Comment: Agreed... I was just presenting the simplest form that would work.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not for a school assignment.  This is me just doing this on my own time.